# Importing banner ads (adsense) in chrome extension (external JS required)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to implement the mobile banner in my chrome extension and I need to have the JS in a separate file as I cannot use internal javascript. How is this done?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<script async 
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- meme -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-1312075280725715"
data-ad-slot="5364641987"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been trying to implement ads for months and have a limited understanding of how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. It's a violation of the AdSense policies -- if you succeed, your AdSense account will probably be disabled.

> Currently, AdSense may not be used to serve ads in Chrome Extensions or Chrome Apps, per AdSense policies.

-- https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#ads

(I'm not sure exactly what part of the AdSense policies apply here, but if Google says it's against their own policies, I'm inclined to believe them!)

Comment: I won't disobey their rules! I am still trying to figure this out though. I don't know where to start! Thank you for your help!